# UIAlertView gives an error

Tags: ios, uialertview

My alertview gives this problem.. it has nothing to do with sqlite.. it gives gives some information..

how can i fix this?

```
UIAlertView *infoShow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"info"
                                                       message: @"info."
                                                      delegate: nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];


    [infoShow show];
    [infoShow release];




Unable to load persistent store at URL 'file://localhost/Users/Mac/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 409;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "5D722675-4764-4953-9508-7CBA29078E68";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually a problem. This seems to happen recently with new versions of the SDK. It's something internally to the iPhone simulator that happens usually when you open a keyboard (spot the error talking about keyboards).

This shouldn't affect your app's running but if it is then try resetting your simulator - there is a menu option for it. That should fix it.

Comment: yes my app is running with no problems.. im just a bit afraid that my app will be rejected lol.. i just reset my simulator and now im not getting that error.. cheers..

Answer (score 0):

You are right -- it has nothing to do with your UIAlertView.  You made a change to your Core Data schema and are now trying to open a earlier version that was saved with an older schema.  Delete (or migrate) the old Core Data store and you should be fine.

Good luck.